# Keycloak login page URL

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I have an angular application integrated with keycloak for authentication and authorization.
Everything is working as expecting but, when I click on login from my application it is redirecting to keycloak server with the GET HTTP call, and the below URL is generated for login page.

```
http://<HOST:PORT>/auth/realms/microsoft/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&state=<state_token>&response_mode=fragment&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=openid&nonce=<nonce_token>
```

Our security team suspects displaying the redirect_uri, nonce token etc might lead to security issues.

I am assuming the URL is generated by keycloak-service of angular, below is the configuration.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { KeycloakService } from "keycloak-angular";

@Injectable()
export class KeycloakAuth {

  init(keycloak: KeycloakService, environment) {
    const tenant: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    if (tenant.has('client') && !window.localStorage.getItem('client')) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('client', 'ient')
    } else if(window.localStorage.getItem('client') && !tenant.has('client')) {
      //
    } else if (tenant.has('client') && window.localStorage.getItem('client')) {
      if (window.localStorage.getItem('client') !== tenant.get('client')) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('client', tenant.get('client'))
      }
    } else {
      window.localStorage.setItem('client', 'ient')
    }

    if (window.localStorage.getItem('client')) {
      return () =>
        keycloak.init({
          config: {
            url:  environment.KEYCLOAK_URL + '/auth',
            realm: window.localStorage.getItem('client'),
            clientId: window.localStorage.getItem('client') + '-app',
          },
          initOptions: {
            onLoad: 'check-sso',
            redirectUri: environment.APP_URL,
            flow: 'implicit',
            silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
              window.location.origin + '' + window.location.pathname + 'assets/silent-check-sso.html',
          },
          bearerExcludedUrls: ['/assets']
        });
    }
  }

}
```

I am wondering if I can do some config change here so those parameters will be injected as part of request/response headers. Or there must be a POST HTTP call.
[**EDIT** - Or can be set token values in cookies or any hidden fields or maybe at session leve, I am open for solutions.]

How can I modify the URL or any blog post if this doesn't lead to security?

Comment: How does moving this info to request header will increase security?

Comment: In theory IDP must support also POST request for auth endpoint. But then I guess your UX team will be asking why you are using a POST and not GET. BTW: Why your security team doesn't worry about used implicit flow (which is obsolete flow)?

Comment: @solveMe, Agree by adding in a request header may not increase security, anything we have an option to add this token data and passing it through cookies or any hidden fields?

Comment: @Jan Garaj, we can have a GET/POST call until those tokens are not exposed.

Comment: I would say really stupid idea - you want to remove parameters (not tokens), which are defined in the OIDC standard https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest e.g. `redirect_uri` is `REQUIRED`. `nonce` is `OPTIONAL`, but it is there to mitigate replay attacks. So your security team wants to remove something, what will open surface for another types of attacks. IMHO your security team doesn't understand OIDC protocol.